# Buying shares on the London Stock Exchange

Tags: united-states

I was researching some companies and one that I was interested in investing in is only traded on the London Stock Exchange. I've searched around and read a little bit on ADRs, but the company in question doesn't appear to offer that.

As an American, is there a straightforward way to buy shares of a company on the London Stock Exchange?

Comment: Have you asked your stock broker? You could look for another stock broker if your current broker doesn't allow you to buy LSE-listed shares.

Comment: @Flux I read through some of their documentation and googled around a bit, but they don't seem to offer it. I think your question/suggestion is essentially the answer I'm looking for. That is, that it's likely possible, I just have to find the right broker?

Comment: Yes, you just have to find the right broker. In the US, you could try Interactive Brokers. It is known for allowing retail investors to buy international stocks.

Comment: @Flux Thanks! If you want to copy that into an answer, I’ll accept it as the answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, you should ask your existing broker whether or not they can buy LSE-listed shares for you. If not, ask a different broker. US citizens and residents are allowed to buy foreign shares, so it is just a matter of finding the right stock broker. In the US, Interactive Brokers is known for allowing retail investors to buy international stocks. Alternatively, you could ask UK stock brokerage firms whether or not they are willing to open an account for an American (some may not be willing because of the paperwork involved).